# Ways to load JavaScript after onclick condition

Tags: javascript, datepicker, load, forms

I have a task to load some JavaScripts for full website and load only on for html form, with data picker. Because DataPicker has some conflicts with other scripts and I don't want to fix 10 other scripts, I want to load only Date Picker for html form.

I can't use html frame.

I need to pass condition when button which open the form is pressed.

My idea was to create and pass Java Script variable to loading form and write a condition for this variable, if it set not to load other JavaScripts and if not set - not load. I didn't code any prototypes yet.

Thanks

Comment: A script is loaded for the whole page. Write which scripts you are using and how they conflict so we can help with that.

Comment: Don't! Don't, Don't do this, fix the root cause